# DS-160 - I was asked more questions than my mom, is that normal?

Tags: visas, usa

My mom and I are planning to visit the US soon for a short period of time, I had 1 more section than she did, is that normal?

This is the section I am talking about:
[DS-160 Form Guide: Additional Work/Education/Training Information](https://www.immihelp.com/visas/ds-160-form/additional-work-education-training-information.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this section is required of only some applicants, depending on their occupation or nationality:

> Please note that this page will be displayed if the Additional Work/Education/Training page is not required (this page is required for nationals of certain countries as discussed below).

And

> Present and Past Work/Education/Training Information
>
> This page is displayed for all applicants with varying amount of information required depending on the Primary Occupation chosen.

Source: http://immigration.dinsmore.com/faq/travel/tips-for-completing-visa-application-form-ds-160